# customize jquery-ui tolltip

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

i use HTML Tables in my project and  show tooltip on  by jquery-ui.
but i want add 'mydiv' as tootip when mouseenter and hide by mouseleave.

```
  <div id="mydiv">
    <input type="button"  value="Delete"/>
    <input type="button"  value="Edit"/>
</div>
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

May be you need [Jquery qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/)

```
$(this).qtip({
      content: divId // Use the contents of the child myqtip-content element.
      style: 'cream'
   });
```

*(please ignore if you do not want to use any plugins)*

Comment: Yeah,that is ok.so you can just add the qtip plugin.really its lightweight and reduce the burden of more lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a perfectly good example of custom content in the demos.

http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content

Click on `view source` to see code and adjust accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Tooltip - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
  });
  </script>
  <style>
  label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5em;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<p><a href="#" title="That's what this widget is">Tooltips</a> can be attached to any element. When you hover
the element with your mouse, the title attribute is displayed in a little box next to the element, just like a native tooltip.</p>
<p>But as it's not a native tooltip, it can be styled. Any themes built with
<a href="http://themeroller.com" title="ThemeRoller: jQuery UI's theme builder application">ThemeRoller</a>
will also style tooltips accordingly.</p>
<p>Tooltips are also useful for form elements, to show some additional information in the context of each field.</p>
<p><label for="age">Your age:</label><input id="age" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes." /></p>
<p>Hover the field to see the tooltip.</p>


</body>
</html>
```

[**Demo** :](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

[More one sample](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/)